# Can I access a value inside some nested objects with just a single string?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I was wondering if it's possible to access a value inside a nested object with just one string. Supose I have an object like this:

```
skill: {
    skillDetails: {
        developerDetails: {
            developerName: "mr. developer"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can do something like this, to get the value via a "JSON path": `skill["skillDetails.developerDetails.developerName"]` ?

The reason I ask this is because I'm trying to pass the `key` & object into a function (that I can't modify) that essentially returns `object[key]`

not sure if this possible so I thought I'd ask you guys for some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: I've just answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53660608/9867451), check it out and adapt the answer to your needs (the inner function is what you're looking for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "built in" method, however a simple solution to this (that doesn't require a third party library) can be achieved via `split()` and `reduce()` as follows:

```js
var skill = {
  skillDetails: {
    developerDetails: {
      developerName: "mr. developer"
    }
  }
}

var path = "skillDetails.developerDetails.developerName";

var value = path
.split('.') // Split path into parts by '.'
.reduce((obj, part) => obj ? obj[part] : undefined, skill); // Extract value via reduction

console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no quick built-in method to accomplish this -- you'll need a helper function.

[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#get) supports this using `_.get(obj, property)`.

From the docs:

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// → 3

_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// → 3

_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// → 'default'
```

Answer (score 1):

The de facto standard with plain JS is to use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) since using its accumulator it allows you to keep "walking the path" until you get to the value, but often the use case where on the path you might have a function is ignored. Here is an example:

```js
var obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      fooBar: "BARFOO",
      foo: function() { return { c: 'BAR' }}
    }
  }
}

const get = (obj, path) => path.split('.').reduce((r,c) => {
  return r ? typeof r === 'function' ? r()[c] : r[c] : undefined
}, obj)

console.log(get(obj, 'foo.bar.fooBar'))
console.log(get(obj, 'foo.bar.foo'))
console.log(get(obj, 'foo.bar.foo.c'))
```

As you can see if you wanted to get the actual value of `foo.bar.foo.c` you have to go through a function and execute it ... now all this is "skipped" if you ware to utilize [`_.result`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#result) from lodash:

```js
var obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      fooBar: "BARFOO",
      foo: function() { return { c: 'BAR' }}
    }
  }
}

console.log(_.result(obj, 'foo.bar.fooBar'))
console.log(_.result(obj, 'foo.bar.foo'))
console.log(_.result(obj, 'foo.bar.foo.c'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Something to keep in mid along with [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) which would only get you values and would not walk through functions and [`_.has`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#has) which would return boolean if `path` is valid or not.